# How to create dynamic pivot tables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am trying to have two pivot tables one after the other, but since their size changes every so often, this means that the first one ends up overlapping the second and thus causing an error. Is there a way to make pivot tables shift cells up and down depending on their size?

I have also tried putting the tables next to each other, and then using a formula to put everything into a single vertical list in another sheet, but I can't seem to find a formula that actually works for this purpose. I need the data sets to be on top of each other, eg:

---

Section A (Pivot 1) || Project Name || Other Details

Section B (Pivot 2) || Project Name || Other Details

Section C (Pivot 3) || Project Name || Other Details

---

I can't manage to figure out a solution to this

Comment: no, there is no way for that. However you can get a pivot table reading data from multiple sources (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-pivottable-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5)

Comment: Interesting. The only thing is that the data source is the same, and all of the pivot tables have identical fields. The only difference between them is the filtered value. I need each pivot table regardless, which is why I am making them all, but I'd also need to 'concatenate' them all into a single sheet in their separate sections. Can you think of a better way to do this?

Comment: Y don't you work with Dynamic named data range for both !!

Comment: How Pivot Table overlap each other since one could assign destination Range for it?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but in that case I have no clue how I would go about creating that dynamic range. I don't think I could somehow get the number of rows of the pivot table and then concatenate that into a range that is used for the next ones start row. Can you point me toward some documentation that shows how to do what you have explained?

Comment: "The only difference between them is the filtered value" - I still don't understand why you need multiple pivot tables.  Maybe some sample data can help us to understand your situation. Anyway, the setup - having dynamic sized pivot tables on top of each other - is not possible in Excel, regardless how valid is your reason to create them.

Comment: It is both a business constraint (All the data must be visible at all times, thus needing multiple tables) and a formatting requirement, since you can't add rows within a pivot table. I need it to be, "Title row with some calculations in it, corresponding pivot table, Next title row, pivot table", and so on. I hope that clarifies that point. I realize that this is an issue with excel, but I am trying to either a) coerce excel to doing what I want, or b) use a method more suited to what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Currently, it seems my best bet is to just use multiple tables and manually add the 'PK' column values and use vlookups/indexmatch to pull the rest of the data through, only issue with that it still requires some manual input. Ideally I'd find a way around that, but if I can't then oh well I guess